# SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server error when beginning transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, smo

Having an error when using SMO.  This code has been working in VB.Net 4 and was just moved to C# and is now not functioning.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(
    new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connStr.ToString())));

server.ConnectionContext.Connect();
server.ConnectionContext.BeginTransaction(); // error here
```

Error is :

> A transaction that was started in a MARS batch is still active at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.

There are no other connections to the database other than the SMO.

The connection string is:

> Data Source=MYPC\SqlServer;Initial Catalog=mytestdb;Integrated Security=True;User ID=;Password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Has anyone seen this error when using SMO and knows what is causing it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling MARS (MultipleActiveResultSets=False)?

Comment: I guess disabling MARS will fix this but I'd hate just changing settings until the code starts to work.

Comment: removing the MARS from the connection string fixed the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing the MARS from the connection string fixed the problem.

Comment: That's not a fix. MARS is there a for a very good reason, so you can run multiple batches in parallel on the same connection.